# ProgrssBar doesn't display on screen

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar

I want to set visible progress bar on my screen while uploading data to DB. But when I put VISIBLE, it doesn't display on my screen. What is wrong?
Here is my Activity class.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private CountryService countryService = new CountryServiceImpl();
        private static final String INSERT_DATA_ITEM_MESSAGE = "Insert data item selected";
        private static final String EXIT_ITEM_MESSAGE = "Exit. Bye, bye";
        private static final String ERROR_DURING_CONVERTING_JSON_TO_MAP_MESSAGE = "Error during converting JSON to Map. ";
        private static final String JSON_FILE_NAME = "countries";
        private static final String ASSET_FOLDER = "raw";
        private static final String DATA_ARE_ALREADY_UPLOADED = "Data are already uploaded";
        private static final String DATA_UPLOADED_SUCCESSFUL = "Data uploaded successful";
        private static final String KEYWORD = "search";
        private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
        private SQLiteConnector sqLiteConnector;
        private Spinner countryListSpinner;
        private ListView listView;
        private List<CountryWithCitiesDto> listCountryiesAndCities;
        private ProgressBar progressBar;

        private Map<String, String[]> getParsedMapFromJSONFile() {
            InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(
                    getResources().getIdentifier(JSON_FILE_NAME,
                            ASSET_FOLDER, getPackageName()));
            byte[] byteArrayFromJSONFile = JSONReader.getByteArrayFromJsonFile(inputStream);
            if (byteArrayFromJSONFile != null) {
                return buildMapFromByteArrayJSONFile(byteArrayFromJSONFile);
            }
            return Collections.emptyMap();
        }


        private Map<String, String[]> buildMapFromByteArrayJSONFile(byte[] jsonByteArray) {
            try {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                return mapper.readValue(jsonByteArray, new TypeReference<Map<String, String[]>>() {
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(ClassNameTags.MAIN_ACTIVITY, ERROR_DURING_CONVERTING_JSON_TO_MAP_MESSAGE + e.getMessage());
                return Collections.emptyMap();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            initDatabase();
            countryListSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.countryListSpinner);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cityListView);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setAdapterToSpinner(setCountryListSpinner());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            countryListSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int position, long arg3) {
                    List<String> cityList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < listCountryiesAndCities.get(position).getCityList().size(); i++) {
                        cityList.add(listCountryiesAndCities.get(position).getCityList().get(i).getNameCity());
                    }
                    setAdapterToCityList(cityList);
                }


                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


                }
            });


            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                        long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WikiActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(KEYWORD, listCountryiesAndCities.get((int) countryListSpinner.getSelectedItemId()).getCityList().get(position).getNameCity());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.insert_data_menu:
                    if (listCountryiesAndCities.isEmpty()) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        uploadFromJsonToDatabase();
                        setAdapterToSpinner(setCountryListSpinner());
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(this, DATA_UPLOADED_SUCCESSFUL, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, DATA_ARE_ALREADY_UPLOADED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    Log.i(ClassNameTags.MAIN_ACTIVITY, INSERT_DATA_ITEM_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                case R.id.exit_menu:
                    Log.i(ClassNameTags.MAIN_ACTIVITY, EXIT_ITEM_MESSAGE);
                    break;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


        private void initDatabase() {
            sqLiteConnector = new SQLiteConnector(this);
            sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteConnector.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        private void uploadFromJsonToDatabase() {
            countryService.insertCountryWithCities(getParsedMapFromJSONFile(), sqLiteDatabase);
        }

        private String[] setCountryListSpinner() {
            listCountryiesAndCities = countryService.getListCountriesWithCities(sqLiteDatabase);
            String[] outArray = new String[listCountryiesAndCities.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < listCountryiesAndCities.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(listCountryiesAndCities.get(i).getCountry().getNameCountry());
                outArray[i] = listCountryiesAndCities.get(i).getCountry().getNameCountry();
            }
            return outArray;
        }

        private void setAdapterToSpinner(String[] spinnerCountryArray) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerCountryArray);
            countryListSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


        private void setAdapterToCityList(List<String> cityNames) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapterToCityList
                    = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    cityNames);
            listView.setAdapter(adapterToCityList);
            adapterToCityList.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }


    }
```

And here is my activity.xml file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.shapoval.countryparser.MainActivity">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="124dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-326dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/cityListView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cityListView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-166dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/countryListSpinner"
        android:layout_width="303dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="47dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cityListView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="361dp"
        android:id="@+id/cityListView"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a negative marginTop, i guess your progressBar is out of screen bounds.

EDIT:

Every time you set your progressBar to View.Visible, three lines after you set it to View.Invisible again. That's why you are not seeing it. If you need to show the progressBar while your data is loading, you should have a listener to know when it is completly loaded to set your progressBar to invisible/gone

Comment: what i must do? remove all margins at my progress bar?

Comment: Try to remove margins and check if it appears. If it does, you have a positioning problem.

Comment: I read again your code and found something weird, check mi edit.

Comment: maybe I need to create new thread that will upload my data and after that invoke thread.join() and set progress bar  invisible?

Comment: Can you know when your countryService has successfully uploaded the data to your database? A listener or something that allows you to tell to your activity that your task has been completed.

Comment: yes. they are upload successfully because result displays on screen

Comment: I'm talking about the code, if you, from code can set a listener to your service to be notified when the task is complete